# After upgrading Python from 2.4 to 2.7 server get down

Tags: python, centos

I installed Python 2.7 on CentOS in a different location, but I didn't change the `PYTHON_PATH` to newly installed Python.  Since then, I am not able to access the system via cPanel or SSH (to revert back the `PYTHON_PATH`).  I'm also not able to access any of the hosted sites in a web browser.  It keeps on looking for host.  However, the site is still pingable from `cmd` with 0% packet loss.

Could changing `PYTHON_PATH` have caused this?  How can I get access to the server now?  :(

Comment: May be host disabled the shell access as i have installed new service??

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: How exactly did you install the new version? From a .rpm? Through Yum with an alternate repo? Or you compiled it? If you compiled it, which configure options did you use exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you installed Python 2.7 into an alternate location (such as `/opt`) but not update any system-wide references to `PYTHON_PATH`.  If you left the system Python 2.4 installed in it's default location, this could not have caused the issues you are describing.

I also gather that this is a VPS.  Does your provider off any out-of-band access to the VM itself?  For example, with Linode they offer the Lish service.

The fact that the VM is pingable may not mean that it's running, depending on the network architecture.  Is the public IP address assigned directly to `eth0` (or whatever the primary device is)?